# Finite groups with exactly one maximal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I was recently reading a proof in which the following property is used (and left as an exercise that I could not prove so far). Here is *exactly* how it is stated.

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose it has exactly one maximal subgroup. Then $G$ is cyclic.

Now, does this mean exactly one *conjugacy class* of *maximal subgroups*? If it really means *exactly one maximal subgroup*, then what can we say about a finite group that possesses exactly one class of (at least two) maximal subgroups that are all conjugate to each other?

Comment: It means "exactly one maximal subgroup".

Comment: Though, as Jack points out, the weaker claim "one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups" in fact implies that there is only one maximal subgroup.

Comment: Let G be a finite group.prove that every proper subgroup of G is in a maximal subgroup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $G$ has only one conjugacy class of maximal subgroup, $M$, and is not itself a $p$-group, then for every prime $p$, $M$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.  But then by Lagrange, $|M|$ has order divisible by every prime power dividing $|G|$, so $|M|$ is a multiple of $|G|$.  Since $|M| \leq |G|$, one must have $|M| = |G|$ and $M = G$, a contradiction.  If $G$ is a $p$-group and one conjugacy class of maximal subgroup, then every maximal subgroup is normal, and so $G$ must have exactly one maximal subgroup, and so is cyclic as before.

In particular, every finite group has at least two classes of maximal subgroups.  The non-abelian group of order 6 has exactly two classes.

It is not too uncommon for a finite group to have only one class of maximal subgroup that is not normal, and one that is normal (so two classes total): every finite *primitive* solvable group is like this.  Depending on your definition, it might just be by definition.  But there are a few definitions that make it sound exciting.

Comment: Two more proofs (including the reduction from an infinite group to the finite case) are given at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=404462

Comment: Another way of proving it is as a corollary to the fact that, if $M$ is a maximal subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $G$ cannot be the union of the conjugates of $M$. To prove that, consider the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets of $M$ and use the fact that a nontrivial transitive permutation representation of $G$ must contain fixed-point-free permutations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your second paragraph should refer to "every finite non-cyclic group".

Comment: @Schmidt The claim that every finite primitive solvable permutation group has two conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups is incorrect. The symmetric group $S_4$ has three classes: $A_4$, $S_3$ and $D_8$. If you meant "primitive linear group", then $GL(2,3)$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 36):

**Definition**: A proper subgroup $M$ of a group $G$ is maximal iff whenever $M \leq H \leq G$, we have $H = M$ or $H = G$.

**Alternative Definition**: A subgroup $M$ of a group $G$ is maximal iff $M \neq G$ and there is no subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $M \subset H \subset G$.

---

**Proposition**:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose it has exactly one maximal subgroup. Then $G$ is cyclic.

**Proof**:

Suppose $M < G$ is the maximal subgroup of finite group $G$. Take $a \in G\setminus M$.

If $H = \langle a\rangle < G$, then there is a maximal subgroup $K$ such that $H\subset K$. Clearly $K \neq M$, which leads to a contradiction to the uniqueness of the maximal subgroup. So $G = H$ must be cyclic. Furthermore, $G$ must be a $p$-group, since otherwise, $G$ would have more than one maximal subgroup.

Comment: use `\langle` and `\rangle` for the angle brackets.

Comment: You'll want to bookmark [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) (drawing an angle bracket brings `\langle` at the top or almost at the top for me), and/or pages with lists of LaTeX symbols, such as [this one](http://omega.albany.edu:8008/Symbols.html).

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, I believe I have it bookmarked...but I've been on a *bookmarking frenzy*...and need bookmarks to bookmark my bookmarks!  I'll put it on my toolbar ;-)

Comment: @Jedrek please give me the reason behind that there is always a maximal subgroup K such that H subset of K.

Comment: why there must be a maximal subgroup which contains $<a>$

Comment: A nice argument. Came up again [today](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4115529/11619). Too bad I had upvoted already back in the day :-)

Answer (score 5):

The argument used to prove that a finite group with a unique maximal subgroup is cyclic can also be used to describe the structure of commutative local rings. I include this as an answer because it highlights a basic trick in algebra.

A ring $A$ is a (commutative) local ring if it has a unique maximal ideal $m$. Let $x\in A$, $x\not\in m$. We assert that $x$ is a unit in $A$. If not, the ideal $(x)=\{xa|a\in A\}$ generated by $x$ is a proper ideal of $A$ and is therefore contained in some maximal ideal of $A$. However, $m$ is the only maximal ideal of $A$ and this proves that $x\in (x)\subseteq m$; a contradiction.

Exercise 1: Prove that if the set of non-units in a commutative ring $A$ is an ideal in $A$, then $A$ is a local ring.

Exercise 2: Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the set of all ordered pairs $(f,U)$ where $U$ is open and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. We define an equivalence relation on this set by setting $(f,U)\equiv (g,V)$ if $f|W=g|W$ for some open subset $W\subseteq U\cap V$. Let us define a ring structure on the set of all equivalence classes $A$ by the rules: $(f,U)+(g,V)=(f+g,U\cap V)$ and $(f,U)\times (g,V)=(f\times g,U\cap V)$. Prove that these operations are well-defined and prove that the ring $A$ in question is a local ring. (Hint: The set of all equivalence classes corresponding to representatives of the form $(f,U)$ such that $f(x)=0$ is the unique maximal ideal of $A$.)

Exercise 3: Is the result of the above exercise true if the word "continuous" is deleted throughout? Is the result of the above exercise true if the words "continuous" *and* "open" are deleted throughout? Is the result of the above exercise true if the word "continuous" is replaced by either "differentiable", "smooth" or "analytic"?

Answer (score 0):

The following fact implies this (it's already covered in the answers above, so this isn't really an original contribution):

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_all_conjugates_is_proper

One application of this is that a finite non-abelian group in which every subgroup is abelian cannot be simple:

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_non-abelian_and_every_proper_subgroup_is_abelian_implies_not_simple

Comment: @ Vipul: you should develop more your answers, not simply give links to your website, although it is certainly well done. The object here is to provide self-contained answers (as far as this is reachable in space and time).

Comment: @Thomas: I don't really see the need to provide an answer, if a link contains exactly the answer for the given question

Comment: I don't mean that the answer is not on his website. What I mean is that this is not a place to make advertisements for his website (what he does in every post he writes). Answers need to be self contained in this forum.