# Groups With Exactly One Maximal Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I understand that when $G$ has exactly one maximal subgroup (inclusion-wise), then $G$ has to be cyclic.

But is it possible to determine all possible groups with exactly one maximal subgroup?

Comment: Is $G$ finite ?

Comment: It does not have to be. If $G$ is finite, I can prove that those are the groups of order $p^n$, for $n > 1$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. All maximal subgroups are proper by definition.

Comment: Ok, that is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the group must be cyclic then classifying all such groups is easy, at least in the finite case, because the lattice of subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to the lattice of divisors of $n$. This lattice has a single maximal element (different from $n$) iff $n$ is a prime power.

Comment: BTW, here is a proof that if a finite group has exactly one maximal subgroup, then it must be cyclic: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39954/589

Comment: A full proof is at http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_of_prime_power_order_iff_not_generated_by_proper_subgroups.