# Finite groups with only one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be finite. Suppose that all maximal subgroups of $G$ are conjugate. Then $G$ is cyclic.

I was stuck, then I find [one solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39941/finite-groups-with-exactly-one-maximal-subgroup). In Jack’s answer, it was mentioned that “one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups in fact implies that there is only one maximal subgroup”.

However, in the beginning of the proof, *Lagrange Theorem* was applied to the **conjugacy class** $M$, which **is not** necessarily **a subgroup**. I’m really confused about this point. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer you mentioned $M$ refers to an element of the conjugacy class rather than the conjugacy class itself. In that answer since each Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal subgroup (which is conjugate to $M$) while all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, it follows that $M$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then the Lagrange theorem implies that $M$ has order divisible by every prime power dividing $|G|$. Thus $|G|$ divides $|M|$.