# If a finite group has exactly $2$ maximal subgroups, then it is $3$-cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, maximal-subgroup

Prove that if a **finite** group has exactly $2$ maximal subgroup, then it is $3$-cyclic.

I tried using the same method as here:

[Finite groups with exactly one maximal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39941/finite-groups-with-exactly-one-maximal-subgroup/39954#39954)

but it leads nowhere.

Comment: sorry for the pedantry, what do you mean by 3-cyclic? Only $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finite groups, this below is maybe a partial answer, but provides you with some insight. You probably know that a group with only one maximal subgroup must be cyclic of prime power order. A group with exactly two maximal subgroups must also be cyclic and has precisely two different primes dividing its order:

**Proposition** If $G$ is a group with exactly two maximal subgroups, then it must be nilpotent.

**Proof** Let $M$ be one of the two maximal subgroups. We have to show that $M$ is normal in $G$. Since $M$ is maximal, we have either $G=N_G(M)$ (equivalent to $M \lhd G)$ or $M=N_G(M)$. In the latter case, and because $|G:N_G(M)|$ is exactly the number of conjugates of $M$, we have $|G:N_G(M)|=2=|G:M|$. And it is well-known that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

**Note** In this proposition one can replace "two" by $p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$.

**Proposition** There exists no $p$-group which has exactly two maximal subgroups.

**Proof** Let $G$ be a $p$-group with exactly two maximal subgroups, and let $\Phi(G)$ be its Frattini subgroup. Then $G/\Phi(G)$ has exactly two maximal subgroups, namely the canonical images of the maximal subgroups of $G$. But $G/\Phi(G)$ is an elementary abelian group say of order $p^n$. If $n=1$ then $G/\Phi(G)$ is cyclic, implying $G$ is cyclic and a cyclic $p$-group has a unique maximal subgroup. Hence $n \geq 2$ and we can find an $N \lhd G$ with $G/N \cong C_p \times C_p$. But then $G/N$ has $p+1$ maximal subgroups and the preimages of those in $G$ yield a contradiction.

**Corollary** If $G$ is a group with exactly two maximal subgroups, then $G \cong C_{p^{a}q^{b}}$, with $p$ and $q$ two different primes.

For this $G$ has to be nilpotent, say $G=P_1 \times \cdots \times P_k$, the direct product of its different Sylow subgroups. It is not difficult to see that the number of maximal subgroups is the *sum* of the number of maximal subgroups of each of the factors. By the previous propositions and the fact that a $p$-group with only one maximal subgroup must be cyclic, the corollary now follows.

The last proposition also implies the following.

**Proposition** Let $p$ be an odd prime. There exists no $p$-group which has exactly three maximal subgroups.

**Proof** Let $M_1, M_2$ and $M_3$ be the maximal subgroups. These all have index $p$ and are normal. Put $N=M_1 \cap M_2$, and assume $N=1$. Then we have $G=M_1M_2$, so $|G|=p^2$, which group has $p+1$ maximal subgroups. So $p+1=3$, a contradiction. Observe that $N \subseteq M_3$, for if not, then $G/N$ has exactly two maximal subgroups, which is impossible by the previous proposition. So $N=M_1 \cap M_2 \cap M_3=\Phi(G)$. Hence $G/N \cong C_p \times \cdots \times C_p $ and this group has $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}=3$ maximal subgroups (with $n \geq 2$). It follows that $p=2=n$ again a contradiction.

Note that $V_4$ and also $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$, have exactly $3$ maximal subgroups. What remains is to classify all $2$-groups with exactly $3$ maximal subgroups.

Comment: Do you know what $3$-cyclic means? I have no idea!

Comment: Not a clue! I really have not heard of it before ..

Comment: I don't know what a 3-cyclic group is either. The group $A_4$ has exactly two maximal subgroups and is not a nilpotent group.

Comment: @kabenyuk Hmm, $A_4$ has 5 maximal subgroups, namely, it's unique Sylow $2$-subgroup ($\cong V_4$) and the $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups (all $\cong C_3$)...

Comment: @Nicky Hekster Yes, I agree, you are correct.

Comment: Well your answer has mysteriously been accepted, despite nobody understanding the question!

Comment: Well it is a classification of groups with only two maximal subgroups after all.